# Why does the routing sometimes add parameters to the URL

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes

I have an issue that is bugging me, as it appears like it is inconsistent behavior. Only it can't be, it must be a gap in my understanding.

I have an action link defined on 2 seperate pages like this. `@Html.ActionLink(" ", "action", "controller", new { enquiryId = item.Id }, new { @class = "icon-user center" })`
On both views the links are in a table. Neither is wrapped in form tags.

Both Method declarations have the same signature, i.e. `public async Task<ActionResult> actionName(int enquiryId = 0)`

However, on one page the URL at the top is 'Controller/Action/`and the other contains the enquiryId as a parameter. eg 'Controller/Action/1`

Both pages contain the relevant data, so I am confused as to why this is happening, and how to remedy it. It doesn't affect the apps performance, it is just bugging me.

The only thing I can see that is different is that The View that does not display the parameter is in the same controller as the page that selected it.

Comment: Are you sure the enquiry id is passing in both action methods.... Just confirm that

Comment: Yes it is, debugger shows that it is there in both, and the controllers are using the parameter to retrieve information from thw database to display it.

Comment: Why does it matter? What issue is it causing you?

Comment: Its not causing any issue. I would just like to know why it is happening for my own education.